Adding annotation to signed pdf using PHP with fpdf and tcpdf removes signature
I'm trying to add a page with an annotation box to an existing signed pdf. This should be possible with TCPDF and FPDF. Unfortunately, it removes the sign and the pdf cannot be validated after being altered. The displayed pdf looks the same, though.
The code (generated by AI) follows:
<?php
use Fpdf\Fpdf;
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once '../lib/fpdf/Fpdf.php';
require_once '../lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
require_once '../lib/fpdi/src/autoload.php';

// require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pdf->setSourceFile('test-form-signed.pdf');

// Loop through the pages of the original PDF
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('test-form-signed.pdf');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
    $tplId = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, 0, 0);
}

// Add a blank new page at the end
$pdf->AddPage();

// Set annotation properties
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->Text(10, 10, "This is a text annotation on a new blank page.");

// Save the output PDF
$pdf->Output('F', 'test-form-annotated-signed.pdf');

The test-form-annotated-signed.pdf is about half the size of the original file and it no longer passes a validation test. Probably, the signature/certificate was removed during the process.
By the way, the pdf is signed with a OCES-3 certificate issued by the State of Denmark.
Please note that solutions that involve using Adobe Acrobat, Signicat etc. are not an option.

As far as I know the point of a signature/certificate is to demonstrate that the PDF is unaltered and the content is original. You want to change the content, yet keep the certificate. That's maybe not possible?

@KIKO Software It is possible to add annotations to a pdf that won't break the signature.

For a list of allowed and disallowed changes see this answer. In other words, it depends on the certification level of the signature in the document whether or not annotations may be added. That addition needs to be applied in incremental updates, though. I don't know whether TCPDF and FPDF support the creation of incremental updates.

You cannot modify an existing PDF with FPDI.
With FPDI you import existing pages into a reusable structure (XObjects) which can be used with e.g. FPDF or TCPDF.
The resulting PDF is a completely new PDF with a completely different internal structure.
Most PDF viewers allow you to annotate signed PDFs (via incremental updates) but will note these modifications.
FWIK: It is impossible to add an additional page without invalidating existing the signatures.

Consider the small text box made with annotations, typically at bottom of the page or on a new page. In the box, information about who signed the document and at what time it was signed along with other info is typically found. In several scenarios, that particular box has to be created after the document itself was signed. This is the case because the user signing the document with his own certificate needs to see the document as part of the signing flow, and at that time the pdf doesn't contain info about the time of signing and ownership.

It is possible to annotate a PDF (while the validator has to decide that this change doesn't invalidate the signature) but it is not possible with FPDI, as it will not allow you to modify an existing PDF.

Thank you, @jan-slabon. Are you aware of another platform/framework where this can be achieved? I'm currently looking at Java and itextpdf, but till now without much luck.

Please find a demo of our SetaPDF-Core component (not free!) that shows you how to add a freetext annotation to a signed PDF here.

I can confirm that using SetaPDF-Core works. Thank you, @JanSlabom.

This can be achieved by using the paid software package, Setasign-Core. The following demonstrates it (code found in the link provided by @JanSlabom in the comments):
<?php

use \SetaPDF_Core_Document_Page_Annotation_FreeText as FreeTextAnnotation;

// load and register the autoload function
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// let's define some properties first
$x = 10;
$yTop = 10; // we take the upper left as the origin

$borderWidth = 1;

$borderColor = '#FF0000';
$fillColor = '#00FF00';
$textColor = '#0000FF';

$text = "Received: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$align = SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_LEFT;

// create a document instance by loading an existing PDF
$writer = new \SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File('test-form-annotated-signed.pdf', true);
$document = \SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename(
    'test-form-signed.pdf',
    $writer
    );

// we will need a font instance
$font = SetaPDF_Core_Font_Standard_Helvetica::create($document);
$fontSize = 12;

// now we create a text block first to know the final size:
$box = new SetaPDF_Core_Text_Block($font, $fontSize);
$box->setTextColor($textColor);
$box->setBorderWidth($borderWidth);
$box->setBorderColor($borderColor);
$box->setBackgroundColor($fillColor);
$box->setAlign($align);
$box->setText($text);
$box->setPadding(2);

$width = $box->getWidth();
$height = $box->getHeight();

// now draw the text block onto a canvas (we add the $borderWidth to show the complete border)
$appearance = SetaPDF_Core_XObject_Form::create($document, [0, 0, $width + $borderWidth, $height + $borderWidth]);
$box->draw($appearance->getCanvas(), $borderWidth / 2, $borderWidth / 2);

// now we need a page and calculate the correct coordinates for our annotation
$page = $document->getCatalog()->getPages()->getPage(1);
// we need its rotation
$rotation = $page->getRotation();
// ...and page boundary box
$box = $page->getBoundary();

// with this information we create a graphic state
$pageGs = new \SetaPDF_Core_Canvas_GraphicState();
switch ($rotation) {
    case 90:
        $pageGs->translate($box->getWidth(), 0);
        break;
    case 180:
        $pageGs->translate($box->getWidth(), $box->getHeight());
        break;
    case 270:
        $pageGs->translate(0, $box->getHeight());
        break;
}

$pageGs->rotate($box->llx, $box->lly, $rotation);
$pageGs->translate($box->llx, $box->lly);

// ...and a helper function to translate coordinates into vectors by using the page graphic state
$f = static function($x, $y) use ($pageGs) {
    $v = new \SetaPDF_Core_Geometry_Vector($x, $y);
    return $v->multiply($pageGs->getCurrentTransformationMatrix());
};

// calculate the ordinate
$y = $page->getHeight() - $height - $yTop;

$ll = $f($x, $y);
$ur = $f($x + $width + $borderWidth, $y + $height + $borderWidth);

// now we create the annotation object:
$annotation = new FreeTextAnnotation(
    [$ll->getX(), $ll->getY(), $ur->getX(), $ur->getY()],
    'Helv',
    $fontSize,
    $borderColor
    );
$annotation->getBorderStyle()->setWidth($borderWidth);
$annotation->setColor($fillColor);
$annotation->setTextLabel("John Dow"); // Used as Author in a Reader application
$annotation->setContents($text);
$annotation->setName(uniqid('', true));
$annotation->setModificationDate(new DateTime());
$annotation->setAppearance($appearance);

// now we need to add some things regarding "variable text" that are required by e.g. Acrobat (if you want to add
// e.g. a digital signature directly after adding a free-text annotation)
$dict = $annotation->getDictionary();
$dict->offsetSet(
    'DS',
    new SetaPDF_Core_Type_String('font: Helvetica, sans-serif ' . sprintf('%.2F', $fontSize) . 'pt;color: ' . $textColor)
    );
switch ($align) {
    case SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_CENTER:
        $align = 'center';
        break;
    case SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_RIGHT:
        $align = 'right';
        break;
    case SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_JUSTIFY:
        $align = 'justify';
        break;
    default:
        $align = 'left';
}

$dict->offsetSet('RC', new SetaPDF_Core_Type_String(
    '<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" ' .
    'xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:11.0.23" xfa:spec="2.0.2"  style="font-size:' . $fontSize . 'pt;text-align:' . $align .
    ';color:' . $textColor . ';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-stretch:normal">' .
    '<p dir="ltr"><span style="font-family:Helvetica">' . htmlentities($annotation->getContents(), ENT_XML1) . '</span></p></body>'
    ));

// lastly add the annotation to the page
$page->getAnnotations()->add($annotation);

$document->save()->finish();

